# AngularJS promise is caching

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, deferred, angular-promise

I think I'm writing my promise incorrectly and I couldn't figure out why it is caching data. What happens is that let's say I'm logged in as scott. When application starts, it will connect to an endpoint to grab listing of device names and device mapping. It works fine at this moment.

When I logout and I don't refresh the browser and I log in as a different user, the device names that scott retrieved on the same browser tab, it is seen by the newly logged in user. However, I can see from my Chrome's network tab that the endpoint got called and it received the correct listing of device names.

So I thought of adding destroyDeviceListing function in my factory hoping I'll be able to clear the values. This function gets called during logout. However, it didn't help. Below is my factory

```
app.factory('DeviceFactory', ['$q','User', 'DeviceAPI', function($q, User, DeviceAPI) {

    var deferredLoad = $q.defer();
    var isLoaded = deferredLoad.promise;
    var _deviceCollection = { deviceIds : undefined };

    isLoaded.then(function(data) {
        _deviceCollection.deviceIds = data;
        return _deviceCollection;
    });

    return {

        destroyDeviceListing : function() {
            _deviceCollection.deviceIds = undefined;
            deferredLoad.resolve(_deviceCollection.deviceIds);
        },

        getDeviceIdListing : function() {

            return isLoaded;
        },

        getDeviceIdMapping : function(deviceIdsEndpoint) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var userData = User.getUserData();

            // REST endpoint call using Restangular library
            RestAPI.setBaseUrl(deviceIdsEndpoint);
            RestAPI.setDefaultRequestParams( { userresourceid : userData.resourceId, tokenresourceid : userData.tokenResourceId, token: userData.bearerToken });
            RestAPI.one('devices').customGET('', { 'token' : userData.bearerToken })
                .then(function(res) {
                    _deviceCollection.deviceIds = _.chain(res)
                        .filter(function(data) {
                            return data.devPrefix != 'iphone'
                        })
                        .map(function(item) {
                            return {
                                devPrefix : item.devPrefix,
                                name : item.attributes[item.devPrefix + '.dyn.prop.name'].toUpperCase(),
                            }
                        })
                        .value();
                    deferredLoad.resolve(_deviceCollection.deviceIds);

                    var deviceIdMapping = _.chain(_deviceCollection.deviceIds)
                        .groupBy('deviceId')
                        .value();

                    deferred.resolve(deviceIdMapping);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}])
```

and below is an extract from my controller, shortened and cleaned version

```
.controller('DeviceController', ['DeviceFactory'], function(DeviceFactory) {

     var deviceIdMappingLoader = DeviceFactory.getDeviceIdMapping('http://10.5.1.7/v1');
     deviceIdMappingLoader.then(function(res) {

        $scope.deviceIdMapping = res;

        var deviceIdListingLoader = DeviceFactory.getDeviceIdListing();
        deviceIdListingLoader.then(function(data) {
            $scope.deviceIDCollection = data;
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Do you expect it to do any caching?

Comment: No, I don't like the cache data. I need to use promise so that I'm sure that data has arrived and I can call the next functions or codes.

Comment: Promise once resolved cannot resolve to a different value again. In the destroy function create the promise again `deferredLoad=$q.defer()`

Comment: Ok, I'll try it. Glad to know, I wasn't aware of it. :)

Comment: I added deferredLoad=$q.defer() into my destroy function. I reloaded my browser so it gets the latest code. Restested but I'm still getting the old value from the previously logged in user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you've only got a single `var deferredLoad` per your whole application. As a promise does represent only one single asynchronous result, the deferred can also be resolved only once. You would need to create a new deferred for each request - although you shouldn't need to [create a deferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) at all, you can just use the promise that you already have.

If you don't want any caching, you should not have global `deferredLoad`, `isLoaded` and `_deviceCollection` variables in your module. Just do

```
app.factory('DeviceFactory', ['$q','User', 'DeviceAPI', function($q, User, DeviceAPI) {
    function getDevices(deviceIdsEndpoint) {
        var userData = User.getUserData();
        // REST endpoint call using Restangular library
        RestAPI.setBaseUrl(deviceIdsEndpoint);
        RestAPI.setDefaultRequestParams( { userresourceid : userData.resourceId, tokenresourceid : userData.tokenResourceId, token: userData.bearerToken });
        return RestAPI.one('devices').customGET('', { 'token' : userData.bearerToken })
        .then(function(res) {
            return _.chain(res)
            .filter(function(data) {
                return data.devPrefix != 'iphone'
            })
            .map(function(item) {
                return {
                    devPrefix : item.devPrefix,
                    name : item.attributes[item.devPrefix + '.dyn.prop.name'].toUpperCase(),
                };
            })
            .value();
        });
    }
    return {
        destroyDeviceListing : function() {
            // no caching - nothing there to be destroyed
        },
        getDeviceIdListing : function(deviceIdsEndpoint) {
            return getDevices(deviceIdsEndpoint)
            .then(function(data) {
                return { deviceIds: data };
            });
        },
        getDeviceIdMapping : function(deviceIdsEndpoint) {
            return this.getDeviceIdListing(deviceIdsEndpoint)
            .then(function(deviceIds) {
                return _.chain(deviceIds)
                .groupBy('deviceId')
                .value();
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

Now, to add caching you'd just create a global promise variable and store the promise there once the request is created:

```
var deviceCollectionPromise = null;
…
return {
    destroyDeviceListing : function() {
        // if nothing is cached:
        if (!deviceCollectionPromise) return;
        // the collection that is stored (or still fetched!)
        deviceCollectionPromise.then(function(collection) {
            // …is invalidated. Notice that mutating the result of a promise
            // is a bad idea in general, but might be necessary here:
            collection.deviceIds = undefined;
        });
        // empty the cache:
        deviceCollectionPromise = null;
    },
    getDeviceIdListing : function(deviceIdsEndpoint) {
        if (!deviceCollectionPromise)
            deviceCollectionPromise = getDevices(deviceIdsEndpoint)
            .then(function(data) {
                return { deviceIds: data };
            });
        return deviceCollectionPromise;
    },
    …
};
```

Comment: Yup, as Chandermani mentioned earlier, I only had one deferred variable. I wasn't aware of it. Trying it now :)

Comment: Just noticed you updated your answer. What if we want to update the cache, how are we going to write a new function called createNewDeviceListing()?

Comment: I think it would be quite similar to the `destroyDiviceListing` function that I posted, depending on what exactly you want it to do.